# How to display explicit null for a multiple columns

Tags: oracle, null

How to display an explicit null for a number of columns in an Oracle SQL? 
To be more specific, I would like to use a SET XXXXXX OFF/ON to display null when a column contains null value as opposed to using NVL for every single column.
Thank you in advance for you advise.

Comment: What environment is the query being run in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SQL*Plus, it has a `SET NULL` command. For example, to display every `NULL` value as an asterisk (`*`), just do this:

```
SET NULL '*'
```

The SQL*Plus default setting is an empty string, so to set it back to default just do this:

```
SET NULL ''
```